# How to get unix executable form of .a library?

Tags: unix

I have a library which i want to use in  my iphone project which uses cpp files as well ... in order to do so i need the unix executable form of .a file..>?

Comment: A static library has no `main()` function, it doesn't do anything on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a program of your own with a `main` function which uses the functions in the library you want to use.  The library doesn't contain any code to exercise its own functions (I won't reiterate what @Steve-o already wrote in the comment -- took the words out of my mouth).  It is fairly common for the source code of a library to include a simple demo program, but this is rarely distributed with the binary library.